# How to enable SSO on a laravel project and integrate it with WHMCS and WordPress

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, whmcs

I have a laravel project on which I want to implement SSO as IDP and use WHMCS and WordPress as SP. After searching I found SAML as a solution but how to use it in laravel and integrate it into WHMCS and Wordpress?.

And through a blog, I came to know that WHMCS does not support SAML then what I can use in that case?.

My main objective is that when I login in my application, Whmcs, and WordPress should also get logged in using SSO.

Comment: You can do that with WHMCS, always login into WHMCS and then login into WordPress if used logged in in into WHMCS

Comment: @ShivSingh But I want it from my Laravel App, That whenever I login into my app, WHMCS, and WordPress should also be logged in with same credentials.

Comment: WHMCS/wordpress uses md5 to for password encryption so same you can use on Laravel and sync WHMCS and Wordpress user passwords by making a cron job plugin of wordpress. Note: you cant login automatic to whmcs automatic but same username and password will work on both.